# Use QuadTree in R to create Geospatial clusters

Tags: r, quadtree, spatial-cluster

I am currently looking into different clustering techniques to form clusters from geospatial data.

Is it possible to utilize quadtrees(from the `SearchTrees` package in R) to come up with something similar to k-means/k-medoid clusters for data points?

Comment: What have you tried? The SearchTrees package only has three functions in it. Did you investigate them?